# Convertir de octal a Hexadecimal da resultado incorrecto

Tags: vb.net

Tengo este código en un Button1Click que pretende convertir en número de octal a hexadecimal.
El tema es que a partir del 16 en octal en adelante da resultado incorrecto y no se corregirlo. ¿Cómo se puede solventar el error?

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'TXTOCT caja octal
        'TXTHEX caja hexadecimal
        Dim CANNUM, OCTBIN, BDIV, TextoBinario As String
        Dim eTxt, TextoOctal As String
        Dim Oct, t, OCTHEX As Long
        Dim REVISAR, HOCT, HDIV As String
        Dim p, Z, Y As Integer
        
        BDIV = ""
        HDIV = ""
        
        Dim A(100) As Long
        
        Oct = Clng(TXTOCT.text)
        
        CANNUM = CStr(TXTOCT.text)
        Z = 0
        Do While Oct > 1
            A(Z) = Oct Mod 2
            BDIV = CStr(Oct \ 2)
            Oct = Oct \ 2
            Z = Z + 1
        Loop
        
        OCTBIN = CStr(A(0))
        For p = 1 To Z - 1
            OCTBIN = OCTBIN & A(p)
        Next
        TextoBinario = OCTBIN & BDIV
        
        ' Invierto el Texto de derecha a izquierda
        eTxt = ""
        For t = Len(TextoBinario) To 1 Step -1
            If (Trim(TXTOCT.Text) = "1" And Len(TXTOCT.Text) = 1) Then
                eTxt = "1"
            Else
                eTxt = eTxt & Mid(TextoBinario, CInt(t), 1)
            End If
        Next t
        TXTHEX.Text = eTxt
        
        Dim H(100) As Long
        Dim K As Integer
        Dim eHx(20) As String
        eHx(12) = "A"
        eHx(13) = "B"
        eHx(14) = "C"
        eHx(15) = "D"
        eHx(16) = "E"
        eHx(17) = "F"
        OCTHEX = CLng(TXTOCT.text)
        K = 0
        Do While (OCTHEX > 17)
            H(CInt(K)) = CLng(OCTHEX Mod 16)
            HDIV = CStr(OCTHEX \ 16)
            OCTHEX = OCTHEX \ 16
            K = K + 1
        Loop
        
        HOCT = CStr(H(0))
        Select Case HOCT
            Case "12"
                HOCT = "A"
            Case "13"
                HOCT = "B"
            Case "14"
                HOCT = "C"
            Case "15"
                HOCT = "D"
            Case "16"
                HOCT = "E"
            Case "17"
                HOCT = "F"
        End Select
        
        Select Case HDIV
            Case "12"
                HDIV = "A"
            Case "13"
                HDIV = "B"
            Case "14"
                HDIV = "C"
            Case "15"
                HDIV = "D"
            Case "16"
                HDIV = "E"
            Case "17"
                HDIV = "F"
        End Select
        
        For Y = 0 To K - 1
            If Y > 0 Then
                REVISAR = CStr(H(CInt(Y)))
                Select Case CStr(REVISAR)
                    Case "12"
                        REVISAR = "A"
                    Case "13"
                        REVISAR = "B"
                    Case "14"
                        REVISAR = "C"
                    Case "15"
                        REVISAR = "D"
                    Case "16"
                        REVISAR = "E"
                    Case "17"
                        REVISAR = "F"
                End Select
                HOCT = HOCT & REVISAR
            End If
        Next
        TextoOctal = HOCT & HDIV
        
        ' Invierto el Texto de derecha a izquierda
        eTxt = ""
        For t = Len(TextoOctal) To 1 Step -1
            eTxt = eTxt & Mid(TextoOctal, CInt(t), 1)
            If (CInt(Trim(TXTOCT.Text)) < 16) Then
                eTxt = TXTOCT.Text
                If (Len(TXTOCT.Text) = 2) Then eTxt = eHx(CInt(Trim(TXTOCT.Text)))
            End If
        Next t
        
        TXTHEX.Text = eTxt
    End Sub
```

Comment: La misma recomendacion que te dimos en todas las preguntas anteriores... que deberia dar? que da? lo probaste? seguiste tu codigo?

Comment: Lo probé sí. Si leyeras arriba dice que  a partir del 16 en octal en adelante da resultado incorrecto.

Comment: Claro.. eso lo entiendo... que resultado te da el 17? que resultado deberia darte? Es la tercer o cuarta pregunta con una tematica similar. No convendria que usaras las funciones que ya te funcionan para hacer esto?

Comment: 17 en octal  da 11 en hexadecimal cuando debería dar F. El 10 en octal da cuadro vacío cuando debería dar 8

Comment: 17 en octal, te esta dando 15 en decimal? hasta esa parte funciona bien?

Comment: si, pero el 10 en octal da cuadro vacío

Comment: porque entonces, estas haciendo mal la conversion de decimal a hexa.. Dividi tu problema en funciones... primero una que pase de octal a decimal... una vez que eso funcione, otra que pase de decimal a hexa.. para ver donde esta tu problema...

Comment: o de octal a binario, fue lo que pensé pero tampoco se corregirlo

Comment: De octal a decimal es lo mas facil.. empeza por ahi... cuando tengas esa funcion que funciona, vemos porque no funciona la otra

Comment: En el programa por lo que veo lo pasa de octal a binario pero de manera errónea

Comment: Por eso te preguntaba si lo habias seguido...

Comment: no, no lo seguí no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de hacer eso, podrías pasar de octal a binario, de binario a decimal y de decimal a hexadecimal, ya que así es más fácil y el usuario final no se dará ni cuenta de tantos cambios de escala...

Para Convertir de Octal a Binario Deberás de Hacer una Cadena de Texto en un Ciclo Cogiendo Dígito a Dígito con estos Casos:

' Escala Octal:
' 0 = "000"
' 1 = "001"
' 2 = "010"
' 3 = "011"
' 4 = "100"
' 5 = "101"
' 6 = "110"
' 7 = "111"
'
'
' Esta Escala Hexadecimal:
' 0 = "0000"
' 1 = "0001"
' 2 = "0010"
' 3 = "0011"
' 4 = "0100"
' 5 = "0101"
' 6 = "0110"
' 7 = "0111"
' 8 = "1000"
' 9 = "1001"
' A = "1010"
' B = "1011"
' C = "1100"
' D = "1101"
' E = "1110"
' F = "1111"
'
'
' Haz un Ciclo Que Coja el Número Octal Dígito a Dígito
' y Forma una Cadena Que Podrás Transformar a Decimal y de Decimal a
' Hexadecimal
' El Bucle Para Convertir de Binario a Decimal debe de Ser una Función
' y a de Ser Así:
'
'

```
Public Function ConvertBinaryToDecimal(ByVal Num1 As String) As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim CuentaDecimal As Integer = 1
    Dim Man As Integer = 0
    Dim Restante As String = Num1
    Dim Resultado As Integer = 0

    For Man = 1 To Len(Num1)
        Dim Numero As String = Right(Restante, Uno)
        If CInt(Numero) = 1 Then
            Resultado = CStr(Resultado + CuentaDecimal)
        Else
            ' No Suma = 0
        End If
        CuentaDecimal = CuentaDecimal * 2
        Restante = Left(Num1, Len(Num1) - Man)
    Next

    Return Resultado

End Function
```